# Is there a way to schedule an automatic WinClone run on my Bootcamp partition?

Tags: macos, backup, boot-camp, scheduled-tasks

I've currently got time machine setup to back up my entire OS X installation. I also have a backup tool within my Bootcamp Windows 7 installation which automatically backs up my windows profile data to an external drive partition. Finally, I'm also backing up my Bootcamp partition weekly and storing on an external drive using WinClone.

The final piece I need to complete my external backup process is to have the WinClone application backup my Bootcamp partition automatically once a week rather than having to call it manually and remember. Is this possible?

Comment: You can try to use Scott's solution to directly invoke `Winclone.app/Contents/Resources/winclone.perl`, or parts thereof -- it's mostly `hdiutil` calls. The whole (AppleScript Studio) application seems to be centered around this script.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Did it work?

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest version, (Winclone 5 at the time of this writing), this is possible using the `winclone_helper_tool` command line application.

See https://twocanoes.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202370406-Running-Winclone-from-the-Command-Line for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Does WinClone have a command-line mode, or does it require the use of a GUI? If it can be called from the command line, then [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/launchd.html) is what you're looking for. Make a copy of `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.periodic-weekly.plist` and modify it to call WinClone.

If WinClone requires use of the GUI, it's a lot harder - though not impossible - to automate. If it's AppleScript-able, use that, otherwise you may be better looking at another application. IIRC, WinClone mainly makes a disk image of your Windows disk - you may be able to get similar functionality from a purely command-line program, such as `hdiutil` or `dd`.

Comment: Winclone is not AppleScriptable, and in fact no longer available for download, since the developer site is down.

Comment: Winclone is based on a bunch of `hdiutil` calls, see my comment on the question. Winclone is still available for download at Softonic.